# React - Remove image based on position within window

Tags: reactjs

I have a video running in the background of my app. The problem is when you go all the way to the bottom of the site, the video pokes out from underneath if you overscroll. I need to not see the video peak out from under the rest of the app.

I'm in React, so it's a bit tricky. I tried this:

```
let styles = "video-foreground"

function parallax(){  
    let ypos = window.pageYOffset; 
    if(ypos > 420) {
        styles = "video-blackout"
    } else {
        styles = "video-foreground"
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax);

CSS

 .video-blackout {
   display: none; 
 }
```

"styles" is the style I put on the video. But this doesn't work well. It sometimes doesn't get rid of the video for a few seconds. Other times it doesn't put the video back after you scroll back up for a few seconds. I'm not sure why the delay happens, but it does.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What I am seeing is nothing "popping out" at the bottom of the page. Tested on Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: I notice that doing the quiz, after the 1st answer, an option is ticked for me on subsequent questions.

Comment: You have to wait a few moments. The video is dark at the beginning. After about 15 seconds of it running, you will see it popping out.

Comment: Fixed that other issue. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

This worked. Injecting the style was creating a delay. Doing it directly worked.

```
function parallax(){  
    let ypos = window.pageYOffset; 
    if(ypos > 420) {
        document.getElementById('banner').style.display = 'none'; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('banner').style.display = 'block'; 
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax);
```